# Angular lazyloaded component error Error: Cannot find 'default'

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-module

I have deployed an angular app via azure devops in production mode. But when want to go any lazyloaded component it give the error

```
    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find 'default' in 
    './problem/problem.module'
    Error: Cannot find 'default' in './problem/problem.module'
```

Note that if i reload any page without index.html it gives error:

```
    The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name 
    changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

the website is :https://tritronfront.azurewebsites.net/
To produce the error you have to click on problem menu on navbar.

My lazy loading route code is

```
    { path: 'admin', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module'},
    { path: 'problem', loadChildren: './problem/problem.module'}
```

and module code is

```
    export default class ProblemModule { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just say:

```
export class ProblemModule { }
```

you have to also add one more thing:

```
{ path: 'problem', loadChildren: './problem/problem.module#ProblemModule'}
```

This is there in the official documentation
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: it didn't fix my problem. even applying your method triggered the problem in my local machine build version also

Comment: thank you it worked . But when i do reload https://tritronfront.azurewebsites.net/login this page then it give error message The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.